# Display based on specific user

Tags: user-roles

I'm struggling to work this out, but can anyone help me on how to write a statement to display a line of text IF the author of a post is equal to a specific USERID?

So for example

**IF THE CURRENT POST**

**IS WRITTEN BY A SPECIFIC USER ID**

**THEN DISPLAY SOME TEXT**

Comment: Provide more details. Is this to be used within the loop, as in a page template? Where will the text appear? What is the nature of the text being displayed (e.g., author meta for the post author)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered using the [get_the_author_meta()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_author_meta) function?  It would look something like this:

```
if (get_the_author_meta('ID') == ID_YOU_ARE_TESTING_FOR) {
     // display text
}
```

This would need to be used within the Loop.